# Visual Basic Reading Binary/Hex

Tags: vb.net, binary, hex

I'm trying to read a list of item names from a bin file but getting an empty/null values when I try console write:

[Hex Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAcGA.png)

The data are a list of item name/information that later planning to put in a listview. I'm putting an offset to binary reader below:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim path As String = "C:\Users\USER\PATH\TO\file.bin"

    Using reader As New IO.BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
        reader.BaseStream.Position = Convert.ToInt64(502004)
        For x = reader.BaseStream.Position To 502173 - 1
            Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadString())
        Next
    End Using

    Console.WriteLine("End")
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no indication of the string length. Use StringBuilder +  `ReadChar()` or `ReadByte()` + Buffer + `Encoding.UTF8.GetString()` or use a FileStream. -- The strings are null-terminated (so check for `\0` or `0`).

Comment: Is my offset correct? I’m not sure if it's correct. I got it at the bottom left corner of the screenshot. I’m using PSPad BTW

Comment: It looks correct, but of course I cannot say whether it's in the same position in that file every time you read it. -- Anyway, don't use `BinaryReader.ReadString()`.

Comment: @groggy You want `&H502004`, not `502004`, and similarly for the `502173`.